# How do I connect to Google Cloud SQL using SSL?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL instance and I want to make the connection between my back end API's and the database as secure as possible. I have specified 'Allow only SSL connections' in my instance settings. I am using the SSL certificates generated by Google, however I am having difficulty working out how to connect securely.

When I connect using:

```
return mysql.createPool({
  host: db_host,
  port: 3306,
  user: db_user,
  password: db_password,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    key: clientKey,
    cert: clientCert,
    ca: serverCa,
  },
});
```

it works fine, however using 'rejectUnauthorized: false', is obviously not secure.

If I remove 'rejectUnauthorized: false', I get the error

```
'Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: ##.##.##.## is not in the cert's list:'
```

It seems I need to connect using the hostname, however Cloud SQL doesnt provide an option to connect using a hostname.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: however you specify `db_host`, that has to be one of the names in the Subject Alt Name extension of the certificate. If you specified `db_host` as an IP address, then that IP address must be a name (of type IP address) in the Subject Alt Name extension of the cert.

Comment: That makes sense, however the certificate was generated by the cloud SQL instance, and it seems the IP address of the instance is not listed in the certificate. I think I also read somewhere that you cant connect to a google cloud SQL instance via a hostname (?). Not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using the Node.js Connector as it will handle the managing of certificates and mTLS connection for you.

Here is how to start a new `mysql2` connection pool.

```js
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';
import {Connector} from '@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector';

const connector = new Connector();
const clientOpts = await connector.getOptions({
  instanceConnectionName: 'my-project:region:my-instance',
  ipType: 'PUBLIC',
});
const pool = await mysql.createPool({
  ...clientOpts,
  user: 'my-user',
  password: 'my-password',
  database: 'db-name',
});
const conn = await pool.getConnection();
const [result] = await conn.query( `SELECT NOW();`);
console.table(result); // prints returned time value from server

await pool.end();
connector.close();
```

More information at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector#using-with-mysql

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer. An amazingly clean and simple implementation that everyone can easily deploy.

Comment: Is there an implementation for PHP in development? I am interested in writing a Laravel package using this connector.

Comment: @JohnHanley No there is not a Cloud SQL PHP Connector currently in development unfortunately.

Comment: @JackWotherspoon - Thank you for the update.

Comment: Thanks. Should this work 'as is' (after changing user, password and database)? I am getting an error and the code seems to be trying to find the google credentials. I have read the documentation and I can see there is an option for Automatic IAM Database Authentication, however should it also work without this?

Comment: Also for other users who may get a 'top-level await' error, I changed 
'await pool.end();' 
to 'void await pool.end();' which worked for me as per https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48499

Comment: @TerenceSweeney the library sources Google Application Default Credentials from the environment where it runs. See [setup Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) for details on setting up ADC creds depending on the environment you are running the code in.

Comment: added a section to the library's README to make this more clear: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector#credentials

Comment: Great. Thanks for that. Is it possible to use a GoogleAuth object as credentials with cloud-sql-connector? If so, how would I pass the  GiogleAuth object?

Comment: @TerenceSweeney no unfortunately passing in a custom `GoogleAuth` credentials object is not currently possible. We have an open [feature request issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/issues/200) for it.

Comment: @TerenceSweeney we have an open PR to implement the feature and it should be released early next week hopefully: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/pull/238

Comment: @JackWotherspoon. Great. Good timing. :)

Comment: @JackWotherspoon I have a follow up question regarding this. Can you help or direct me where the best place is to post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77604648/how-do-i-pass-custom-googleauth-credentials-to-google-cloud-cloud-sql-connector

Comment: @TerenceSweeney feel free to raise an issue on the Cloud SQL Node Connector and label it "question" and our team will be prompt to respond to you :)
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector/issues

Answer (score 1):

There are two certificates issued by Cloud SQL: client and server. Both certificates are self-signed.

The client certificate is used to validate the client's identity (mutual authentication). This certificate is self-signed and Cloud SQL validates the certificate.

The server certificate can be used for the server's identity validation if you write your own verification routine - support for that capability is library specific. Otherwise, disable hostname certificate verification.

Is disabling hostname verification a security concern?

The connection is secure if the client is inside Google Cloud's network because no man-in-the-middle can be installed by a third party. You control the IP address used to initiate the connection.

The connection is at risk if the client is outside of Google Cloud's network. In that case, use the Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy to provide secure encrypted connections.

In almost all cases, I recommend using the [Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. At the moment I am connecting (trying too) from vercel to cloud SQL. I believe Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy will not work with serverless functions. I may have to rethink my setup.

Comment: @TerenceSweeney - You can embed the SQL Auth Proxy in your application. The library is called ***Cloud SQL Connector***. See this link for Node.js: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector Go, Java and Python are also supported: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy